# Can we show Time on Top and Day on Side in timeGrid

Tags: javascript, calendar, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-6

[image]

I want to show time on top and days and others on the side.

I am using full calendar 6.1  I want to show time as a row instead of a column.

I want to show time on top and days and others on the side. I am using full calendar 6.1

**Edit** I have set up a **CodePen** - Please check for demo and clarity. codepen.io/Itxshakil/pen/ExrJyqr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this isn't possible with the [timeGrid](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/timegrid-view) view or any other fullCalendar view currently (the latest version of fullCalendar is 6.1.10 at the time of writing).

The [timeline](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/timeline-view) is the closest you will get, in the sense that the time is across the top, but also the days are across the top too, so it can scroll continously. The vertical axis can then be used for separate "resources" if you wish to split events across different rooms/people/whatever - but this is optional. Note that the timeline view is a [premium feature](https://fullcalendar.io/pricing), however.

If you want to suggest an inverted timeGrid view, or vote for any existing suggestions for it which may exist, please take a look at fullCalendar's documentation about [requesting features](https://fullcalendar.io/requesting-features).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed information, I have requested a feature but I need to build this on my own. I'll update you when it is available.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, this should definitely be possible but I can't help you without any source code. Could you please include all relevant source code to this question (maybe even in a jsfiddle or similar) so that I and others could take a look at it?

Comment: I have setup a codepen for this. https://codepen.io/Itxshakil/pen/ExrJyqr

Comment: Thanks for showing interest, but you should use comments for questions.